# Laravel 5.1 Ajax code 500

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I've a problem with my ajax-call in Laravel 5.1.
If I had a sequence ajax call (for example 10) Laravel, randomatically, responde me with a error code 500 and "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

My ajaxcall is:

```
data.forEach(function(e,i,a){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/api/insert",
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            method:"POST",
            data: {"text":txt, "lat": lat, "lng":lng, "title":i},
            success:function(ret){
                console.log(ret);
            }
        });
    }
```

i've not a problem with my data, it's seem Laravel have a problem with a consecutive ajaxcall

Comment: Turn on debug mode to see what are you're getting.

Comment: i've this .env: APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: Well, what's in the error log then..?

Comment: And what does the network pane say the response for this ajax request is? If you have errors displaying, you should be able to see this in the network pane of inspect element. EDIT: And are you sure your meta selector is returning the token correctly? Console.log it.

Comment: i've ONLY this error, no other log info. The token is correct

Answer (score 1):

### About AJAX

Let's assume that each AJAX request takes ~1 second to process. If you run AJAX in a `forEach` loop like this, then you might assume that 10 operations take ~10 seconds.

```
Time     Action
0:00.00  Send Request 1
0:01.00  Receive Response 1 #(~1 second later)
0:01.00  Send Request 2
0:02.00  Receive Response 2
0:02.00  Send Request 3
0:03.00  Receive Response 3
...
```

However, **AJAX calls do not work like this**. You are sending all 10 of these requests at approximately the same time. For example,

```
Time     Action
0:00.00  Send Request 1
0:00.01  Send Request 2
0:00.02  Send Request 3 #(basically no difference from Request 1)
0:01.01  Receive Response 1 #(~1 second later)
0:01.15  Receive Response 3 #(received before Response 2)
0:04.01  Receive Response 2 #(received much later than Response 3)
...
```

**A few key points**

- All of the requests are sent at *almost* exactly the same moment.
- There is no guarantee that you will get the responses in the same order that you sent them.
- There is a chance that any one of these requests will fail. This will not necessarily cause the other requests to fail.

### How to learn more

To get a better idea of what is happening, you can use your browser's console's Network tools to see what is happening. In Google Chrome, you can hit `[Control]-[Shift]-[J]` to open the developer console. There's a tab called *Network* that will let you look at each request and the response that the server replied with. Other browsers will have similar tools.

[image: The Google Chrome Developers Tool's Network Tab, showing the network traffic of this page]

You can also look at any responses that failed. They might show debugging information, or a stack trace, or a specific server problem that you can resolve.

Comment: i know that, but it's not my problem. I don't wanna the response in the same order, i just wanna all success in my ajax-call. I've not a info about error, just "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: @Stefano - your best action is to enable error messages. You can configure Laravel to show the errors in the response (it looks like you tried to do this with `APP_DEBUG`, but no success), or you can have it write any server errors to a [log file](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging).

Answer (score 0):

I had a heck of time getting ajax to work in Laravel 5.1. Using `contentType` and `processData`, and using the `headers` argument like below was the magic formula that finally got it to work for me. Omitting any one of those caused it to fail.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

<script>

var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

$.ajax({
    type         : 'POST',
    url          : '/api/insert',
    data         : {"text":txt, "lat": lat, "lng":lng, "title":i},
    cache        : false,
    contentType  : false,
    processData  : false,
    headers      : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    dataType     : 'json',
    success      : function(ret) {
        console.log(ret);
    }

    // ....
});
</script>
```